# nvidia-settings not saving powermizer setting for underclock

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 21.10, nvidia-settings

I've been trying to underclock my GPU as I do on all distros for stability as my card is getting old and will crash certain games at default clock speeds. I'm on Ubuntu 21.10 on X11 and I have enabled coolbits=24. When I go to PowerMizer in nvidia-settings, I type in my graphics clock and memory transfer rate offset to both -90. When I press enter after typing the values in, nothing changes whatsoever. Usually after pressing enter I will see the values decrease by 90 on the Max value for the performance levels above where I enter the offsets. I'm using an EVGA GTX 980 ti SC

Am I doing anything wrong? This happens whether I run nvidia-settings as user or as sudo. The max graphics clock on level 3 is supposed to be 1403 with my underclock.

[image: nvidia-settings screen after entering offset and pressing enter]

Edit: I just now found out how to set it via the terminal, but it warns me that it is a read-only attribute.

[image: nvidia-settings commands output]

[image: alternate command]

Comment: In your ```NVidia X Server Settings``` I see at the bottom ```Prefered Mode``` is set to ```Auto```. What if you changed that?

Comment: Sorry for slow reply, yes I've tried changing it. The options available are just Adaptive and Prefer Maximum Performance. Everything I've tried and looked at so far points to it just being an issue with 21.10, since it works perfectly on 20.04 with the same setup and configurations. 

I've rolled back to 20.04 for the time being since it works, but I'm still gonna be poking around at this because I want to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.

Updating from 20.04 worked fine, however, if I do a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 install, it doesn't work. I can't change the card clocks.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1231637)